# Check a macro definition using strings

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, microcontroller

I am not sure whether macros can be used in this way.

In my project on embedded systems, I would like to know if a macro is defined or not depending upon two strings i have.

For eg :

```
#define FAN_1 PORTAbits.RA0

#define LIGHT_1 PORTAbits.RA1
```

Now, when i get a request in the form of :

```
char *arg1="FAN"; ("LIGHT")

char *arg2="1";
```

Using these two arguments i would like to directly check the pin that my fan 1 is attached and check its state.

I want a way so that i do not have to check arg1 and arg2 using strcmp() or direct matching.
And i can directly write `if(some_macro(arg1,arg2)==1){} else {}`.

Please guide if this is possible using macros because pins can only be defined like this.

Also, if not , then is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like microchip PIC code.  If you are using the MPLAB C compiler and libraries, be aware of the difference between strings in RAM vs ROM.  A string constant passed into a function will by a `char rom *`, not a `char *`.  There are special functions in their library for each type of string comparison.  For example:  `strcmppgm2ram(arg1, "FAN")` is correct for comparing arg1 against a string literal.  I'm not sure how other C compilers handle the bizarre memory structure.

Answer (score 4):

No, macros cannot be used like this. Macros are a preprocessor feature which are expanded by the preprocessor before the code is compiled. It sounds like the requests that you receive are only known at runtime. There is no way to check whether the request is for FAN_1 or LIGHT_1 at preprocessor time if this information is only known at runtime. You need to use conditional checks to determine what the request is for.

Depending on the names of the pin banks ("FAN", "LIGHT", etc.), it might be sufficient to switch on just the first character of `arg1`, or perhaps the first few characters. Also, rather than fully parsing `arg2` into an integer, you could switch on characters of that as well. This would allow you to identify the pin that is being requested without needing to call `strcmp()` or `atoi()`.

Comment: Beat me by eight seconds with a more comprehensive answer, +1.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!! i cannot switch at first character of arg1 as i also need to validate if the request is accepted or rejected. For that i have to check the spell complete "fan" and "light" You are right about arg2.

Answer (score 1):

C preprocessor don't have an access to values of any variables. But you can use environment variables instead of macros:

```
putenv("FAN_1", "PORTAbits.RA0")
putenv("LIGHT_1", "PORTAbits.RA1")
```

And then:

```
if (getenv(construct(arg1, arg2)) != NULL) {} else {}
```

Where `construct(arg1, arg2)` function returns concatenation of strings `arg1`, `"_"`, and `arg2`.

Comment: `construct` in this case likely leaks memory.

Comment: He probably doesn't have putenv() or getenv() on a PIC :).

Comment: Right Brian.. i do not have such methods.! Can u suggest any other way to do it .?

Answer (score 0):

GCC supports macro stringification:
[3.4 Stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)